# RestAPI authentication with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, api, rest

I am trying to access the API of OpenProvider using PowerShell and I can't seem to get past Authentication.

The documentation for the API is here : https://support.openprovider.eu/hc/en-us/articles/360025683173-Getting-started-with-Openprovider-API

And my code looks like this:

```
$EndPoint = "https://api.openprovider.eu/v1beta/auth/login"

function Get-ConfHeaders 
{
##Configure headers
$Headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$Headers.Add("ip","0.0.0.0") 
$Headers.Add("username","myusername") 
$Headers.Add("hash","APIpasswordhashgoeshere") 

return $Headers

}

$header = Get-ConfHeaders

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $EndPoint -Headers $header
```

The response get is :

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
At line:36 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $EndPoint -Headers $header
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

I am by no means an expert when it comes to API and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: added the content type and tried the password instead of the hash but I get the same 500 error.

Comment: Try with powershell 5 if you're on 7 currently, Invoke-RestMethod had some breaking changes for Core.

Comment: I've tried the same thing in PostMan and I still get the 500 error but I also get  "desc": "Empty username field!", "code": 901
}

Comment: If you pass anything in the body you get Invoke-RestMethod : {"desc":"Invalid request","code":80}

Comment: Can you confirm that you enabled the API ? https://support.openprovider.eu/hc/en-us/articles/360015453220-How-to-enable-API-access

Comment: Once the API is enabled, retry your command but try to pass the information through the body. Curl -d is a body operation (Reference: https://virtuallysober.com/2019/03/12/converting-curl-to-powershell-for-rest-apis/) I understand that it did not work when you tried it but I believe it might be because you did not specifically toggled on the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think the API documentation here leaves a lot to be desired.

You need to include the authentication in the body and it needs to be converted to JSON format. So the working code looks like this:-

```
$EndPoint = "https://api.openprovider.eu/v1beta/auth/login"

function Get-ConfHeaders
{
##Configure headers
$Headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$Headers.Add("ip","0.0.0.0") 
$Headers.Add("username","username") 
$Headers.Add("password","passwordhere") 
return $Headers
}

$header = Get-ConfHeaders | ConvertTo-Json

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $EndPoint -body $header -ContentType 'application/json'
```

Thanks for the help everyone.